# libqt5webchannel.so.5 missing or not found in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 14.04, deb, qt5, webkit

I am trying to create deb of QT 5.5 app which uses QT5 webkit and webkitwidgets in it. When I am trying to create deb with command "debuild -kMYGPGKEY" then it gives me below error.

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libQt5WebChannel.so.5, needed by /home/myusername/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKit.so.5.5.0, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)

/home/myusername/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKit.so.5.5.0: undefined reference to `QAccelerometer::QAccelerometer(QObject*)'
/home/myusername/Qt5.5.0/5.5/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebKit.so.5.5.0: undefined reference to `QRotationReading::x() const'
```

any many more these types of undefined reference errors.

From the error I found that libQt5WebKit is taking the reference libQt5WebChannel which is not found in my machine.

So if anybody has any idea about the issue or how can I install libqt5webchannel.so.5  in Ubuntu 16.04 then please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: (lib)qt5webchannel-devel-5.x.x is available for "all" new  'Linux OS´s' , except Debian and Debian clones like Ubuntu, Mint. ...

Comment: What is the output of: lsb_release -a

Comment: Here is the output of lsb_release -a - No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial

Answer (score 1):

(Run into a similar problem with https://github.com/GPUOpen-Tools/CodeXL)

## Solution :

sudo apt install libqt5webchannel5-dev

## Explication

The good habit is to look onto https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/libqt5webchannel5-dev site with the missing file/library name and change "package names" into "package contents" at the bar search.

Answer (score 0):

Building qt5webchannel :

```
git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qtwebchannel.git
qmake-qt5
make
sudo make install
```

---

EDIT : Sorry, fails with Ubuntu16.04 :

No `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/QApplication` ... That could be the reason for no `qtwebchannel` in Debian, Ubuntu : A less complete Qt5 ?

Comment: Yes Knud Larsen, this path /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui/QApplication is not exist in 16.04.  I need to create deb of QT 5.5 app in 16.04. So is there any alternate  way to install qtwebchannel in Ubuntu 16.04 machine ?

Comment: » install qtwebchannel in Ubuntu 16.04 machine « : I don't know. What I know is : Easy to build in rpm based OS. They use a different Qt5 structure / patching. Besides that, it is already available for install, as packages, in : Fedora, PCLinuxOS 2016, Mageia, Suse. ....  » I need to create deb ... 16.04 « : Well, nobody else did, I think. I can try if a build from an rpm based OS can be installed in 16.04 .

Comment: Knud Larsen, Thanks for your comment. I will do more research on the same to solve qt5 web channel issue.

Comment: Now I am not getting libqt5webchannel.so.5 missing error (which is dependency of qt webkit) in Ubuntu 16.04. Till now I was using Ubuntu 14.04 compatible debian/rule file in Ubuntu 16.04 machine during creating debian package. I just made changes in debian/rule file as per Ubuntu  16.04 and it works.  But I did not know how to install qt5webchannel in Ubuntu 16.04.